# Timelinejs, 2sxc change font and language

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, timeline.js

I'm trying to change the language and font, but can't find the necessary entries.
Does one of you have an idea? I've already tried different things, but it knocks my timeline and the display module is empty.

Timeline V2, self hosted in DNN CE 9.8.0

Answer (score 0):

The projects includes a file /assets/styles.css. You should be able to add your CSS there. As a quick example:

```
.vco-timeline h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
```

So that would  be an example of a way to change the font. Not sure about how you would use the language features in this case/app. Hopefully someone else chimes in on that.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, good new year.
You mean something like this here in styles.css?
I have try but seen nothing, sorry.

>.timeline-embed {width: 100%!important;height: 500px!important; }
.vco-timeline h2 {font-family: 'Lekton', sans-serif !important; }

Comment: Did you try it with Arial and/or Helvetica first, like in my example? I chose those because a) they are defaults and work in the browsers as is, without loading/pathing the font(s) and b) clearly different than the serif'd default font. It will definitely work. My guess is that it won't work for Lekton until you first get that loading or in place from somewhere.